# Track exit link and ads with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-adsense, jquery

I want to track exit links on my website and also exit ads like Google Adsense etc. I mean by exit ads is that when click on add I get ads dimension and ads type like Google or other ads. In short I want this: Google Adsense *160x600* like in `statcounter.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Burhan,

I'm trying to answer this as short as possible. Click-tracking is something you cannot do with PHP on the click itself. It is possible to have the backend do the tracking (via unique IDs, `$_POST` and a [simple tracking script](http://www.phpdevtips.com/2011/07/simple-advanced-click-tracking-using-php-and-mysql/)).

It is also possible to do with Javascript, if you have your own tracking solution another way would be to trigger the [clicktrack through Ajax via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889190/jquery-click-tracking-with-php) and have a PHP-script count the clicks.

For Google Adsense ads a clicktracking solution is also possible, but it will definately [break the terms and conditions](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms), since you are not allowed to change, alter or modify anything inside or over the ads.

Comment: i have added more info about my problem below please tell me solution

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do there, sorry. I don't know the content of adds.php, nor do I know how you integrate it on your page, what the javascript in your "answer" is supposed to do, nor a lot of other things necessary to provide you with a turnkey solutions. You need to either specify your question, or for programming related questions -> Stackoverflow would be the better place to ask ... ;) In short, you can't change, add or modify things in an iFrame. You need to 'overlay' the iFrame with your own content and do the click-tracking on your overlay. Like a heatmap would.

Comment: script works when i change $('#aswift_0').load(function() but when i change load to click like this $('#aswift_0').click(function() it stop working

Answer (score 1):

i have made a script which works on links but not on iframe generated by google adsense. I have added click event on iframe but it is not working.

```
$('#aswift_0').click(function() {
    var width = $(this).attr('width');
    var height = $(this).attr('height');
    var webid = "1";
    new Image().src = "adds.php/?width=" + escape(width) +   "&height=" + escape(height) + "&webid=" + escape(webid);
    // new Image().src = "adds.php/?width=" + escape (width) + "&height=" + escape (height) + "";
});
```

It works when i change click to load